# Prove that $φ^x$ is close to an integer $y : x = 2^{n - 1}(2^n - 1)$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, golden-ratio, perfect-numbers

I have a question.

I have recently discovered that if you get the golden ratio $φ$, which is equal to $\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}$, then if you raise this to the power of $2^{n - 1}(2^n - 1)$, the higher the value of $n$, the closer this comes to an integer. It does not converge to a particular integer, but just gets very close to some integer. Let this integer be $y$.

I know that the expression $2^{n - 1}(2^n - 1)$ attains perfect numbers, which are numbers that are the sum of all its divisors. And if $2^n - 1$ is prime, then $2^n - 1$ is a Mersenne prime.

Let's call this formula $x$. By testing $φ^x$ with the value $n \leq 30$ (on a $2000$ digit calculator), I have seen that it gets closer and closer to some integer $y$. I have also seen that if there is a Mersenne prime that divides into $x$ then $y$ is divisible by it as well.

However, I cannot prove that this is true. Just by looking at some equation and seeing similar results does not mean I have proven it works for all results (which I can't test because $n$ can tend to infinity), so how do I prove/disprove that $φ^x$ gets closer to an integer $y$ the higher the value of $n?$

I would appreciate it if you showed me step by step and not skip all the steps and possibly show a formula that proves/disproves this if there is one. Thanks.

Comment: I could not use the tag (mersenne-primes) because I do not have $1000$ reputation.

Comment: After Ross Millikna's answer, consider how large are the exponents. If $n=3,4,5,6$, the exponents are $28,120,496,2016$.

Comment: For the above exponents, the value of $\left(\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2\right)^k$ is $\approx 1.4\times 10^{-6}$, $\approx 8.3\times 10^{-26}$, $\approx 2.2\times 10^{-104}$, $\approx 4.8\times 10^{-422}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any connection with Mersenne numbers is a red herring.  We have $\left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2\right)^n+ \left(\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2\right)^n$ is exactly an integer for even $n$ because all the terms with odd powers of $\sqrt 5$ cancel.  Because $\left|\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2\right|\lt 1$ when we raise it to a large power it becomes very small, so $\left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2\right)^n$ becomes very close to an integer for large even $n$.  It also doesn't depend on the base being $\varphi$.  Any quadratic surd with conjugate smaller than $1$ in absolute value shows the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ross. I really appreciated it :)

Comment: I will also point out that the Fibonacci sequence is perfectly given by $F_n=\text{round}(\varphi^n/\sqrt{5})$